# Can ‘why’ and ‘that’ be used together here?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I’ve seen this sentence:

> This essay will explain **that why** united nations has failed.

What I don’t understand here is why ‘that’ and ‘why’ are used next to each other.

Comment: The sentence in your title is incorrect; it should be _...will explain why the United Nations has failed_.

Comment: That would be a grammar error in English.  Where did you read that title of an essay.

Comment: Actually I am asking this question that can we use"why" and"that" together

Comment: @BijaraniHaider We can't. It's a mistake

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's asking why a grammar error is correct, so no answer is possible

Answer (score 3):

"that why" are not used adjacent to one another in anything like either of the suggested sentences:

> - This essay will discuss that why the organization has failed. [image: Red X, indicating incorrect form]
> - This essay will explain that why united nations has failed. [image: Red X, indicating incorrect form]

Either one could be used alone, as in:

> - This essay will explain that the United Nations has failed. [image: Green check mark, indicting correct form]
> - This essay will explain why the United Nations has failed. [image: Green check mark, indicting correct form]

In each of these the key word ("that" or "why") seves as the hd of the clause which acts as the object of the verb "explain". Since the clause cannot have two heads, we don't need or what both used together in this way.

The words "that" and "why" can be used in teh same sentence, each introducing a separate clause. Fopr example:

> - This essay will explain that lack of enforcement power is why the United Nations has failed. [image: Green check mark, indicting correct form]

but not immediately adjacent as "that why".

(Note that "United Nations" takes the definite article "the" in this construction. As a proer noun it is capitalized )

Answer (score 0):

As others have rightly pointed out it is incorrect. Your question was "What I don’t understand here is why ‘that’ and ‘why’ are used next to each other" and that you have seen that sentence somewhere.

It's because the sentence has been written by a non-native speaker whose language allows for "that" and "why" to occur together. For example, that structure is quite normal in both of my mother tongues; i.e. Azeri and Persian.

Many times, non-native speakers fall back on their mother tongue and make such mistakes.

We can paraphrase the sentence in a different way as well:

This essay will explain the reasons for the failure of the United Nations.